# How to keep the pen functions on 14.04 LTS or 15.04

Tags: upgrade, wacom

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad x61 convertible laptop. On 12.04 LTS, everything I want working does. The pen is especially important. I did an upgrade to 14.04 LTS and on a separate occasion, an upgrade to 15.04, and both times I lost all pen functions. a separate mouse worked fine, but the pen didn't. So, what do I exclude fron the upgrade to ensure my functioning digitizer (Wacom) and pen functions continue to work?

Answer (score 0):

Determine why your pen and digitizer work now - what software supports them, and how that software is configured. Read the changelogs for your target Ubuntu version, and see if the supporting software is mentioned. If so, read very carefully.